# Create a datatable containing the Nth digit of each of a list of file names

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have a list of files containing output from a large model.
I load these as a datatable using:

```
files <- list.files(path.expand("/XYZ/"), pattern = ".*\\.rds", full.names =    TRUE)
dt<- as.data.table(files)
```

This datatable "dt" has just 1 column, the file name.
e.g XZY_00_34234.rds

the 50th and 51st character of each file name is a number.
I want to create a datatable containing that 2 digit number for each file.

I used:

```
index <- as.data.table(as.integer(substr(dt,50,51)))
```

This gives me the correct value for the first file.
I think I should be able to use apply to run this against each row of the file

I tried:

```
integers <- as.data.table(apply(dt,1,as.integer(substr(50,51))))
```

But get:

Error in substr(50, 51) : argument "stop" is missing, with no default

Any suggestions gratefully accepted!

Comment: `integers <- as.data.table(apply(dt, 1, function(x) as.integer(substr(x, 50, 51))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
integers <- as.data.table(apply(dt, 1, function(x) as.integer(substr(x, 50, 51))))
```

The `apply` family of functions accept other functions and executes them over vectors and arrays. These functions are some times already defined, but an interesting feature was added to `apply` functions, you can write the function right there at the line for the first time. This saves time and keystrokes.

A narrower programming setup would require your function to first be written like:

```
fiftieth_char <- function(x) {
  as.integer(substr(x, 50, 51))
}
```

Next, that function could then be passed to the `apply` function.

```
apply(dt, 1, fiftieth_char)
```

But look how we were able to do those two steps in one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just `1` column, you could extract the column as a `vector` and use `substr` directly on it instead of looping with `apply`.  For `data.table`, extracting a column is using `?Extract` functions `[[` or `$`.

```
 as.data.table(as.integer(substr(dt[[1]], 50, 51)))
```

Or

```
 as.data.table(as.integer(substr(dt$files, 50, 51)))
```

I noticed that you are creating 'dt' as a data.table from 'files'.  The output of `list.files()` is a `vector`, so instead of creating the data.table first, you could `substr` the `vector` and wrap it with `as.data.table`.

```
as.data.table(as.integer(files, 50, 51))
```

As an example,

```
files <- c('ABC_25', 'DEF_39')
dt <- as.data.table(files)
as.integer(substr(dt[[1]], 5, 6))
#[1] 25 39
as.integer(substr(files, 5, 6))
#[1] 25 39
```